# How to deploy your Xamarin iOS to the web as a progressive web application (PWA)

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, progressive-web-apps

I am new to Xamarin and I have successfully created an application in Xamarin for iOS. What I need is a way for this application to be viewed in the browser as a PWA. I figured to learn xamarin because I thought that this was a useful resource.

I have looked in to ooui but I can't successfully attach my Xamarin project to ooui.

At the end of this project I will have a running PWA coded in c# for iOS in the browser.

A link to the Xamarin can be found here:
https://github.com/SunRhythms/iosslidingpuzzle/tree/master/iOSSlidingPuzzle-3

Comment: https://xamarinhelp.com/create-a-pwa-in-xamarin-forms-with-ooui-wasm/ https://github.com/praeclarum/Ooui

Comment: I guess what I am attempting to ask is if I have a build in iOS native already done how could I complete the ooui as there isn't any resources for that use case...

Comment: You have this tagged w/ `Xamarin.Forms` ... If this is a native `Xamarin.iOS` app, then I personally do not know of any "auto" ways to port it to PWA, you would have to re-code the app (well at least the UI part, assuming it is based on  MVVM/MVC/Viper/... models so you can reuse the backend of the app). Of course there are also professional consultancies that focus/specialize on "app porting" if time is an issue but cost is not 

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Xamarin! Your github repo is set to Private in it's setting.

Gathering from your other question as well, it's clear that you are using Native Xamarin.iOS and not Xamarin.Forms. (They have several differences if you check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32204807/when-to-use-xamarin-forms-vs-xamarin-native/32205377#32205377))

Presently, there is no way of porting your Xamarin.iOS project into a PWA that has been made public. If you do convert your project manually into a Xamarin.Forms project, you could potentially use Ooui to convert Xamarin Forms into high performance WebAssembly code.

It seems like you have a sliding puzzle game, so it would be cool if you do end up doing it! Share it with us and the rest of the Xamarin community